# Why does VirtualBox not detect my Android device?

Tags: windows-7, usb, virtualbox, android

Using VirtualBox 4.2.12, I've set up a Lubuntu 13.04 VM on a Windows 7 host. I specified a USB filter for my Galaxy S, but neither the VM nor VirtualBox detects it.

After searching the internet, I found `vboxmanage list usbhost`, which does not show my device connected. However, `adb devices` does list the device, and I can see it in Device Manager. All drivers on the host are up to date.

It seems to me that if I can get VirtualBox to recognize the device, I shouldn't have a problem getting the VM to. So, how come VirtualBox doesn't?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make my Virtualbox Vista see my USB device (iPad)?](http://superuser.com/questions/306172/how-can-i-make-my-virtualbox-vista-see-my-usb-device-ipad)

Comment: I read that post before asking my question. I don't think I even get that far. VirtualBox doesn't even detect the device, so it can't attempt to hand anything over to the VM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working. There were a couple of things that I learned that might be helpful. First of all, I was following [this guide](http://binglongx.wordpress.com/2013/03/05/use-android-devices-for-guest-ubuntu-os-in-virtualbox-on-windows-7-host/).

VirtualBox currently has problems with USB 3 ports. Check that your device is plugged into a USB 2 port. After I did that, my device was able to be detected by `vboxmanage list usbhost` on my Windows host.

Unfortunately, this didn't completely solve my issue. VirtualBox would list the phone under the Devices menu, and I could select it, but Lubuntu gave me no indication that a device was connected. In fact, `lsusb` and `adb devices` both came up empty. I ran `dmesg` and found this error message:

```
[ 846.648000] usb 1-1: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 1
[ 846.675000] usb 1-1: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[ 846.884000] usb 1-1: device descriptor read/64, error -32
```

I found the following [thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=797789) and set this variable, which solved my problem.

```
echo Y | sudo tee /sys/module/usbcore/parameters/old_scheme_first
```

**EDIT** I discovered that the problem came up again during restart. After a LOT of trial and error, I found that each time I start up, I have to connect the Android device, then set the `old_scheme_first` variable, then disconnect and reconnect the device before the VM would recognize it. It's an annoying process, so if anyone has any insight, I'd appreciate it. On the other hand, it's a VM, so I won't have to restart it often =)

Comment: Figured anything more out? I have the same issue except nothing in dmesg. vboxmanage sees the device and I setup VBox with the extensions and added my device in the usb settings, but nothing in the guest OS. Maybe because I am using Linux Mint?

Comment: @JacobPhillips Sorry, I don't have any more info for you. It's been a while since I've dealt with the issue. Make sure you're not trying to use a USB 3 port?